# ArcGIS Javascript 4.25: Coded value descriptions in popuptemplate

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

Please help. I am using ArcGIS JavaScript 4.25 to display values in a popup using Query on a featurelayer (ArcGIS Server). The coded value is shown in the popup instead of the related description.
[image]

However, I can see the coded values with the descriptions in the web service.

[image]

How do I get the descriptions into the popup ?

Comment: Is your service public and you can share a working example?  You could also try with the latest version, 4.26, but I don't think that will change anything here.
It seems to work fine when I try with https://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/ServiceRequest/FeatureServer/0 -- does that work/fail for you?

Comment: Hi Bjorn, thank you for your reply. I am actually using a map service and not a feature service (https://law.drdlr.gov.za/server/rest/services/LAW_Spatial_Admin_Boundaries/MapServer/124)

I am using the query.executeQueryJSON(searchurl, searchParams) function to return the attributes,
which I then use to create a feature layer and the adds it to the map.

The result from executeQueryJSON does not does not contain the subtype values, 
and I cannot see a property where I can specify that.